# d3 clear svg .remove

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to have a d3 heatmap update based on a dropdown menu.  Currently, it will draw, but when I run the update function d3 hangs on to the previous x-axis labels and appends the function call data to the previous data.  The code snippet I think better shows what's happening.  I have looked at all of the options for the .remove, but nothing seems to work.  I even try to reset the data to empty when the call happens to try to overwrite the data variable, but it still gets cached somehow!  Any help would be fantastic.

```js
var response = [{
    "sample_date": "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ubiome": [ 
      {
        "taxon": 2,
        "parent": 131567,
        "count": 56085,
        "count_norm": 999999,
        "tax_name": "Bacteria",
        "tax_rank": "superkingdom"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 237,
        "parent": 49546,
        "count": 284,
        "count_norm": 5063,
        "tax_name": "Flavobacterium",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 543,
        "parent": 91347,
        "count": 21,
        "count_norm": 374,
        "tax_name": "Enterobacteriaceae",
        "tax_rank": "family"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 579,
        "parent": 543,
        "count": 21,
        "count_norm": 374,
        "tax_name": "Kluyvera",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 712,
        "parent": 135625,
        "count": 2,
        "count_norm": 35,
        "tax_name": "Pasteurellaceae",
        "tax_rank": "family"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 724,
        "parent": 712,
        "count": 2,
        "count_norm": 35,
        "tax_name": "Haemophilus",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 729,
        "parent": 724,
        "count": 2,
        "count_norm": 35,
        "tax_name": "Haemophilus parainfluenzae",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 815,
        "parent": 171549,
        "count": 14662,
        "count_norm": 261424,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroidaceae",
        "tax_rank": "family"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 816,
        "parent": 815,
        "count": 14625,
        "count_norm": 260764,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 817,
        "parent": 816,
        "count": 72,
        "count_norm": 1283,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides fragilis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 818,
        "parent": 816,
        "count": 208,
        "count_norm": 3708,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 820,
        "parent": 816,
        "count": 41,
        "count_norm": 731,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides uniformis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 821,
        "parent": 816,
        "count": 3490,
        "count_norm": 62226,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides vulgatus",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 823,
        "parent": 375288,
        "count": 120,
        "count_norm": 2139,
        "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 201174,
        "parent": 2,
        "count": 562,
        "count_norm": 10020,
        "tax_name": "Actinobacteria",
        "tax_rank": "phylum"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 203494,
        "parent": 74201,
        "count": 81,
        "count_norm": 1444,
        "tax_name": "Verrucomicrobiae",
        "tax_rank": "class"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 203557,
        "parent": 48461,
        "count": 81,
        "count_norm": 1444,
        "tax_name": "Verrucomicrobiaceae",
        "tax_rank": "family"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 204430,
        "parent": 65842,
        "count": 12,
        "count_norm": 213,
        "tax_name": "Fibrobacteria",
        "tax_rank": "class"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 204431,
        "parent": 218872,
        "count": 12,
        "count_norm": 213,
        "tax_name": "Fibrobacteraceae",
        "tax_rank": "family"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 207244,
        "parent": 186803,
        "count": 71,
        "count_norm": 1265,
        "tax_name": "Anaerostipes",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sample_date": "2017-07-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ubiome": [
      {
        "taxon": 2,
        "parent": 131567,
        "count": 67163,
        "count_norm": 1000000,
        "tax_name": "Bacteria",
        "tax_rank": "superkingdom"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 237,
        "parent": 49546,
        "count": 44,
        "count_norm": 655,
        "tax_name": "Flavobacterium",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 543,
        "parent": 91347,
        "count": 401,
        "count_norm": 5970,
        "tax_name": "Enterobacteriaceae",
        "tax_rank": "family"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 547,
        "parent": 543,
        "count": 9,
        "count_norm": 134,
        "tax_name": "Enterobacter",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 579,
        "parent": 543,
        "count": 371,
        "count_norm": 5523,
        "tax_name": "Kluyvera",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 712,
        "parent": 135625,
        "count": 2,
        "count_norm": 29,
        "tax_name": "Pasteurellaceae",
        "tax_rank": "family"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 724,
        "parent": 712,
        "count": 2,
        "count_norm": 29,
        "tax_name": "Haemophilus",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 729,
        "parent": 724,
        "count": 2,
        "count_norm": 29,
        "tax_name": "Haemophilus parainfluenzae",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 815,
        "parent": 171549,
        "count": 13036,
        "count_norm": 194094,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroidaceae",
        "tax_rank": "family"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 816,
        "parent": 815,
        "count": 13031,
        "count_norm": 194020,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 823,
        "parent": 375288,
        "count": 179,
        "count_norm": 2665,
        "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 832,
        "parent": 204431,
        "count": 13,
        "count_norm": 193,
        "tax_name": "Fibrobacter",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 841,
        "parent": 186803,
        "count": 1740,
        "count_norm": 25907,
        "tax_name": "Roseburia",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 853,
          "parent": 216851,
          "count": 6555,
          "count_norm": 97598,
          "tax_name": "Faecalibacterium prausnitzii",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 872,
          "parent": 194924,
          "count": 28,
          "count_norm": 416,
          "tax_name": "Desulfovibrio",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 904,
          "parent": 909930,
          "count": 470,
          "count_norm": 6997,
          "tax_name": "Acidaminococcus",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 906,
          "parent": 31977,
          "count": 2,
          "count_norm": 29,
          "tax_name": "Megasphaera",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 976,
          "parent": 68336,
          "count": 18694,
          "count_norm": 278337,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroidetes",
          "tax_rank": "phylum"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 1301,
          "parent": 1300,
          "count": 33,
          "count_norm": 491,
          "tax_name": "Streptococcus",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 1318,
          "parent": 1301,
          "count": 7,
          "count_norm": 104,
          "tax_name": "Streptococcus parasanguinis",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 1322,
          "parent": 572511,
          "count": 2,
          "count_norm": 29,
          "tax_name": "Blautia hansenii",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 1350,
          "parent": 81852,
          "count": 28,
          "count_norm": 416,
          "tax_name": "Enterococcus",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 1496,
          "parent": 1481960,
          "count": 159,
          "count_norm": 2367,
          "tax_name": "Peptoclostridium difficile",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 1578,
          "parent": 33958,
          "count": 40,
          "count_norm": 595,
          "tax_name": "Lactobacillus",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 1584,
          "parent": 1578,
          "count": 30,
          "count_norm": 446,
          "tax_name": "Lactobacillus delbrueckii",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 1654,
          "parent": 2049,
          "count": 11,
          "count_norm": 163,
          "tax_name": "Actinomyces",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 1660,
          "parent": 1654,
          "count": 11,
          "count_norm": 163,
          "tax_name": "Actinomyces odontolyticus",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 1678,
          "parent": 31953,
          "count": 85,
          "count_norm": 1265,
          "tax_name": "Bifidobacterium",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 2049,
          "parent": 85005,
          "count": 11,
          "count_norm": 163,
          "tax_name": "Actinomycetaceae",
          "tax_rank": "family"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 28026,
          "parent": 1678,
          "count": 6,
          "count_norm": 89,
          "tax_name": "Bifidobacterium pseudocatenulatum",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 28050,
          "parent": 186803,
          "count": 774,
          "count_norm": 11524,
          "tax_name": "Lachnospira",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 28052,
          "parent": 28050,
          "count": 652,
          "count_norm": 9707,
          "tax_name": "Lachnospira pectinoschiza",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 28116,
          "parent": 816,
          "count": 1815,
          "count_norm": 27023,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides ovatus",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 28117,
          "parent": 239759,
          "count": 1356,
          "count_norm": 20189,
          "tax_name": "Alistipes putredinis",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 28118,
          "parent": 283168,
          "count": 91,
          "count_norm": 1354,
          "tax_name": "Odoribacter splanchnicus",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 40545,
          "parent": 40544,
          "count": 432,
          "count_norm": 6432,
          "tax_name": "Sutterella wadsworthensis",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 44748,
          "parent": 541000,
          "count": 15,
          "count_norm": 223,
          "tax_name": "Sporobacter",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 46205,
          "parent": 186803,
          "count": 2258,
          "count_norm": 33619,
          "tax_name": "Pseudobutyrivibrio",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 46503,
          "parent": 375288,
          "count": 190,
          "count_norm": 2828,
          "tax_name": "Parabacteroides merdae",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 47678,
          "parent": 816,
          "count": 537,
          "count_norm": 7995,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides caccae",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 48461,
          "parent": 203494,
          "count": 2075,
          "count_norm": 30894,
          "tax_name": "Verrucomicrobiales",
          "tax_rank": "order"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 49546,
          "parent": 200644,
          "count": 44,
          "count_norm": 655,
          "tax_name": "Flavobacteriaceae",
          "tax_rank": "family"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 51290,
          "parent": 2,
          "count": 2108,
          "count_norm": 31386,
          "tax_name": "Chlamydiae/Verrucomicrobia group",
          "tax_rank": "superphylum"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 52784,
          "parent": 541000,
          "count": 11,
          "count_norm": 163,
          "tax_name": "Anaerofilum",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 68336,
          "parent": 2,
          "count": 18694,
          "count_norm": 278337,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroidetes/Chlorobi group",
          "tax_rank": "superphylum"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 68525,
          "parent": 1224,
          "count": 475,
          "count_norm": 7072,
          "tax_name": "delta/epsilon subdivisions",
          "tax_rank": "subphylum"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 73098,
          "parent": 579,
          "count": 371,
          "count_norm": 5523,
          "tax_name": "Kluyvera georgiana",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 74201,
          "parent": 51290,
          "count": 2075,
          "count_norm": 30894,
          "tax_name": "Verrucomicrobia",
          "tax_rank": "phylum"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 74426,
          "parent": 102106,
          "count": 107,
          "count_norm": 1593,
          "tax_name": "Collinsella aerofaciens",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 80840,
          "parent": 28216,
          "count": 1444,
          "count_norm": 21499,
          "tax_name": "Burkholderiales",
          "tax_rank": "order"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 81852,
          "parent": 186826,
          "count": 28,
          "count_norm": 416,
          "tax_name": "Enterococcaceae",
          "tax_rank": "family"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 106588,
          "parent": 1017280,
          "count": 24,
          "count_norm": 357,
          "tax_name": "Pseudoflavonifractor capillosus",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 115543,
          "parent": 186803,
          "count": 5,
          "count_norm": 74,
          "tax_name": "Parasporobacterium",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 117743,
          "parent": 976,
          "count": 44,
          "count_norm": 655,
          "tax_name": "Flavobacteriia",
          "tax_rank": "class"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 119852,
          "parent": 541000,
          "count": 1079,
          "count_norm": 16065,
          "tax_name": "Oscillospira",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 128827,
          "parent": 526525,
          "count": 807,
          "count_norm": 12015,
          "tax_name": "Erysipelotrichaceae",
          "tax_rank": "family"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 131550,
          "parent": 2,
          "count": 13,
          "count_norm": 193,
          "tax_name": "Fibrobacteres/Acidobacteria group",
          "tax_rank": "superphylum"
        }
    ]
  }
];

var dates = [];
var bacteria = [];

var itemHeight = 30,
  itemWidth = 12,
  cellSize = itemHeight - 1,
  margin = {
    top: 120,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 80
  };

  updateHeatMap();

  function updateHeatMap(option){

    var data;
    d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();
    d3.selectAll("svg").remove();

    var e = document.getElementById("level");
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    var title = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
    var newtitle = document.getElementById("thelevel").innerHTML=title;

    //d3.json("./javascripts/biome/biome_new.json").then(function(response) {
      var data = response;

      data.forEach(e => e.ubiome = e.ubiome.filter(e => e.tax_rank === value));

      dates = data.map(function(d) {
        return d.sample_date;
      })

      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        bacteria.push(data[i].ubiome.slice(0, data[i].ubiome.length));
      }
      var bacteriaList = d3.merge(bacteria).map(function(d) {
        return d.tax_name
      });

      bacteriaList = d3.set(bacteriaList).values();

      var width = bacteriaList.length*itemWidth,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var y_elements = dates,
        x_elements = bacteriaList;

      var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(x_elements)
        .range([0, x_elements.length * itemWidth]);

      var xAxis = d3.axisTop()
        .scale(xScale)
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
          return d;
        });

      var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(y_elements)
        .range([0, y_elements.length * itemHeight]);

      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(yScale)
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
          return  moment(d).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        });

      var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateOrRd)
        .domain([0, 10000]);

      var svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
        .append("svg")
        .attr("id","themap")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var parents = svg.selectAll('svg')
        .data(data)
        .enter().append('g')
        .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate(0," + yScale(d.sample_date) + ")" });

      var children = parents.selectAll('rect')
        .data(function(d) { return d.ubiome; })
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'cell')
        .attr('width', 15)
        .attr('height', cellSize)
        .attr('x', function(d) {  return xScale(d.tax_name); })
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
          return colorScale(d.count_norm);
        });

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .selectAll('text')
        .attr('font-weight', 'normal');

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("id","thexaxis")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll('text')
        .attr('font-weight', 'normal')
        .style("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("dx", ".8em")
        .attr("dy", "1.2em")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "rotate(-90)";
        });
    //});
  };
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #000;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
#heatmap {
  height: 400px;
  width: 1200px;
  border:2px solid #000;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <h4>Sort by:</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column"><select id="level" style="margin-bottom:20px;" onchange="updateHeatMap()"><option value="class" selected>Class</option><option value="family">Family</option><option value="genus">Genus</option><option value="order">Order</option><option value="phylum">Phylum</option><option value="species">Species</option><option value="subclass">Subclass</option><option value="suborder">Suborder</option><option value="subphylum">Subphylum</option><option value="superphylum">Superphylum</option></select></div>
        <div
            class="column">
            <div id="thelevel"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="heatmap"></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/heatmap9.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```